# Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible and if $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $f(x)$ then $\frac{-1}{a+1}$ is also a root of $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> **Problem:** Let $n$ be any integer. Consider this polynomial
>   $$f(x) = x^3 + n x^2 + (n-3)x - 1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$$ Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible and if $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $f(x)$ then $\frac{-1}{a+1}$ is also a root of $f(x)$.

Could we use the Eisenstein's criterion to solve?

Comment: Hint:  A cubic is irreducible over a field $\mathbb F$ if and only if it has no root in that field.

Comment: Eisenstein requires that all coefficients (except the highest one) is divisible by the same prime. The constant term is $1$. I would say that disqualifies Eisenstein as an option, at least directly. It's possible you could use Eisenstein on $f(x+1)$ or something, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: A cubic polynomial over a commutative field will be reducible if and only if it admits a root in that field, so your task is reduced to show $f$ has no rational roots. How you do that is by appealing to the Newton-Gauss lemma according to which a root $\frac{m}{n}$ in reduced form must have the numerator a divisor of the free term and the denominator $n$ a divisor of the leading coefficient; in your case this forces $m, n= \pm 1$. Well, are either $1$ or $-1$ roots of $f$?

Comment: As to the second claim, express $f(-\frac{1}{X+1})$ as a rational fraction in reduced terms and check manually that the numerator becomes a multiple of $f$ itself. This boils down to some calculations, shouldn't be difficult at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the irreduciblility, the rational root test implies that the polynomial does not have a rational root since $1,-1$ are not roots, so it is irreducible since its degree is $3$.

For the second compute $f({1\over{a+1}})={{(-1)^3}\over{(a+1)^3}}+
+n{{(-1)^2}\over{(a+1)^2}}+(n-3){{(-1)}\over{a+1}}-1=$

${{(-1)^3}\over{(a+1)^3}}(1-n(a+1)+(n-3)(a+1)^2+(a+1)^3$

We have $(1-n(a+1)+(n-3)(a+1)^2+(a+1)^3=1-n(a+1)+$

$(n-3)(a^2+2a+1)+a^3+3a^2+3a+1=$

$=a^3+na^2+(n-3)a-1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $x=\frac{-1}{a+1}$ in $f(x)=0$ we obtain:
$$
-a^3-na^2-(n-3)a+1=0
$$